# ASP CODEPAGE 65001 and Mysql 5 utf-8

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, utf-8

```
charset = UTF-8

CODEPAGE = 65001

MySql version: 5.0.92-enterprise-gpl-log

ADO.Version = 2.8
```

When I performe a search with unicode characters, like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (utf8) VALUE ('♂')
SELECT utf8 FROM table WHERE utf8 = '♂' // \u2642
```

Where `utf8` is VARCHAR collation `utf8_unicode_ci`

MySql return 0 rows.

Removing `CODEPAGE=65001` MySql return 1 row. BUT Server.HTMLEncode now return weird symbols and utf8 characters now have length > 1. Not a big deal.

**edit:**

Ok, now I'm confused: this query works:

```
SELECT utf8 FROM table WHERE CONVERT(utf8 USING latin1) COLLATE latin1_general_ci = '♂'
```

obviously this is bad, it ignore INDEXs.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Do not include string literals in ASP script that have characters outside of the ASCII range.  The script engine parser doesn't do multi-byte character sets.  Use ChrW with the Unicode value for other characters.